# Как через форму загрузить картинку по ссылке с сайта?

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет.
Есть такой код на стороннем сайте

```
<input id="js_5p" class="_n" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="" title="Выберите файл для загрузки"></input>
```

Пре клике на кнопку эту появляется проводник в которому нужно Выбрать изображение на своем ПК. Так вот. Я хочу засунуть туда изображение с другого сайт а по ссылке - `http://s018.radikal.ru/i505/1201/8b/6160c138cf0d.jpg`
Как реализовать такую задачу? Подскажите.

Comment: "засунуть туда" - куда? `<img src="http://s018.radikal.ru/i505/1201/8b/6160c138cf0d.jpg" />`

Comment: Можно просто сделать инпут, куда вставляется ссылка, а дальше как [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url)

Такой вариант подходит?

Comment: Это я форму Фейсбука питаюсь заставить загрузить изображение не с моего компьютера, а с сайта по прямой ссылке на изображение.

Comment: Когда проводник открывается, там в путь к файлу пишите ссылку на изображение из интернета. По-моему должно работать

Comment: Нет, так он грузит картинку сначала на комп а потом отдает адрес уже с компа. Я так с начала тоже пробовал. Не получается.

Никогда не любил этот ФБ